# Archiving my .xcworkspace file fails

Tags: ios, xcode

My app reside in a .xcworkspace file. It builds and run fine, but when I try to Archive it (to get the .IPA file) i get:

xcodebuild: error: The directory XXXXXX contains 2 projects, including multiple projects with the current extension (.xcodeproj). Specify the project to use with the -project option.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This hiccup happens switching between sim and device builds sometimes. Try restarting XCode, clean the project and try to archive and see if it helps.